# Schedulercontrol hide ContextMenu

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

How is it possible to hide the contextmenu of a devexpress schedulercontrol? There are two contextmenus, First one is the one on the rightclick in a timecell. That is the one I can hide succesfully in the PopupMenuShowing event.
But the second one is the one on rightclick an appointment especially. And this one i am not able to hide. 
Someone can help me in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach with handling the [ShedullerControl.PopupMenuShowing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraSchedulerSchedulerControl_PopupMenuShowingtopic) event should helps with hiding the context menu for any elements of the SchedulerControl(e.g. appointments):

```
void schedulerControl1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Menu.Items.Clear();
}
```

P.S. This question are already discussed in the following [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) thread: [How to disable right click menu of Appointments](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q427580.aspx).
P.P.S: You can check the exact menu type via the `e.Menu.Id` event handler parameter(for appointment menu it equals to `SchedulerMenuItemId.AppointmentMenu`). The types of all possible popup menu items are listed in the [DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerMenuItemId](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraSchedulerSchedulerMenuItemIdEnumtopic) enumeration.

Comment: What about if you are using MVC?